# Auto detect links in tableview UILabel

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, hyperlink, uilabel

I've found quite some stuff on this topic. I just want links that appear in my label are automatically detected as links and hyperlinked. I've looked at the three20 project TTtwitter, but this look really complex and I don't know where to start for integrating this.

Does anyone know if this can be done on a easy way, or can somebody try to explain me?

Thnx in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Will suggest you to go with `UIWebView`

Use the below property of `UIWebView` for detecting link ..

```
@property(nonatomic) UIDataDetectorTypes dataDetectorTypes
```

Comment: But the text I currently have is loaded in a Label, can I set all the properties just like label? For instance number of lines.

Comment: Btw, i'm working with a tableView with customs cell. These custom cell have labels in them. Should i just change it from UILabel to UIWebView?

Comment: @peter :Yes, you need to change from UILabel to UIWebView

Comment: I've tried to change it but it doesnt act the way I need. Link get opened it the same uiwebview, and since this is a subview of a cell of a table view this doesnt works on the right way. Besides that I can only click on the link when userinteraction is enabled. Since i'm using this for expanding and retracting the cell there are some problems with this.

Answer (score 0):

You can't underline text in UILabels or UIButtons. Here's what I did with a similar situation.

I wanted to have underlined text in a view that looked like a link but I didn't want the functionality of a UIWebView and I needed standard target/action UIControl functionality. What I did only works if you have a single line of text that you want to display and have look like a link. Use this as you would a standard UIButton. You should create with type = UIButtonTypeCustom.

I created a subclass of UIButton that supports underlining for a single line of text by overriding `drawRect`. I added a `BOOL _titleLabelUnderlined` iVar to the subclass.

### XButton.m

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
   // just in case...
   [super drawRect];

   if (_titleLabelUnderlined) {
        CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

        // determine the size of the titleLabel text based on the font
        CGSize textSize =[self.titleLabel.text sizeWithFont:self.titleLabel.font 
                                                   forWidth:self.bounds.size.width
                                              lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeTailTruncation];

        // set the underline color
        CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, self.currentTitleColor.CGColor);

        // line width
        CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 1.0f);

        // calc the start and end points for the line
        CGFloat minX = self.titleLabel.center.x - textSize.width/2.0f;
        CGFloat maxX = self.titleLabel.center.x + textSize.width/2.0f;

        // start the line
        CGContextMoveToPoint(context, minX, CGRectGetMinY(self.titleLabel.frame) + CGRectGetHeight(self.titleLabel.frame) + 1.0f);

        // draw the line to the end point
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, maxX, CGRectGetMinY(self.titleLabel.frame) + CGRectGetHeight(self.titleLabel.frame) + 1.0f);

        // commit the drawing
        CGContextStrokePath(context);
    }
}
```